# Unicode error in inputenc package

Tags: beamer, equations

My beamer presentation presents this problem `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char − (U+2212)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \end{frame}`. I tried remove some elements and I see that problem appear when I use `-` in equation. I'd like one hint about this problem.

```
\documentclass[pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Convergência - Prova}
    %\justifying
    Sem perda de generalidade a demonstração foi focada numa partícula unidimensional. Reescrevendo a Equação, tem-se que
    \begin{equation}
    x_i(t + 1) + \alpha_1 x_i(t) + \alpha_2 x_i(t − 1) = \alpha_3
    \end{equation}
    onde
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \alpha_1 &= (1 + \omega) + u(r_1 - r'_1)c_1 + u(r_2 -r'_2)c_2 + c_1r{'}_1 + c_2r'_2 \\
    \alpha_2 &= \omega \\
    \alpha_3 &= u(r_1 - r'_1)c_1p + uc_2(r_2g - r'_2n) + c_1r'_1p + c_2r'_2n                    
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Sorry by english

Comment: In my notebook only exists one symbol. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, the `xelatex`solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Which notebook? What the `-` key ends up giving is generally up to the editor you are using.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unicode U+2212 is MINUS SIGN, which is not set up by default with `inputenc`. Just add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
```

to your preamble, just before `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Convergência - Prova}
    %\justifying
    Sem perda de generalidade a demonstração foi focada numa partícula unidimensional. Reescrevendo a Equação, tem-se que
    \begin{equation}
    x_i(t + 1) + \alpha_1 x_i(t) + \alpha_2 x_i(t − 1) = \alpha_3
    \end{equation}
    onde
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \alpha_1 &= (1 + \omega) + u(r_1 - r'_1)c_1 + u(r_2 -r'_2)c_2 + c_1r{'}_1 + c_2r'_2 \\
    \alpha_2 &= \omega \\
    \alpha_3 &= u(r_1 - r'_1)c_1p + uc_2(r_2g - r'_2n) + c_1r'_1p + c_2r'_2n                    
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will do the right thing even without searching for the offending character (you possibly got it from copy-paste).

[image]

Comment: Doesn't `utf-8` support the minus sign?

Comment: @adosar Not currently.